# Ionic 2 cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation Not Updating UI

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm new to Ionic and Typescript so apologies if I have this arse about face !

Im trying to build a simple iOS and Android app with Ionic 2 that simply displays the users current location, updating as they move.

The issue I am facing is that whilst I appear to be getting the co-ordinate locations come through the UI never updates to display the updated location.

I have created a provider using the cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation plugin as location.ts:

```
import { Injectable, NgZone} from '@angular/core';
import { BackgroundGeolocation } from 'ionic-native';

@Injectable()
export class LocationProvider {

public message: any = "I'm new here";
public latitude:number = 0.0;
public longitude:number = 0.0;
private zone: NgZone;

constructor() {
   this.initialiseLocationManager();
}

initialiseLocationManager() {

let config = {
        desiredAccuracy: 1,
        stationaryRadius: 1,
        distanceFilter: 1,
        interval:1000,
        activityType:'AutomotiveNavigation',
        debug: true,
        stopOnTerminate: true,
};

BackgroundGeolocation.configure(config)
     .then(this.locationUpdated)
     .catch((error) => {
          console.log('BackgroundGeolocation error');
      });
}

private locationUpdated(location) {
   console.log('******* NEW LOCATION ********');
   this.zone.run(() => {
     this.latitude = location.latitude;
     this.longitude = location.longitude;
 });

 BackgroundGeolocation.finish(); // FOR IOS ONLY
}

private error(error) {
   console.log('ERROR');
}

public startTracking() {
  BackgroundGeolocation.start();
}

public stopTracking() {
   BackgroundGeolocation.stop();
}
}
```

I am then injecting this into my page test.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import {LocationProvider} from '../../providers/location/location';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/test/test.html', 
})
export class TestPage {

  constructor(private nav: NavController, private     locationProvider:LocationProvider) {

  }

  startTracking() {
    this.locationProvider.startTracking();
  }

  stopTracking() {
    this.locationProvider.stopTracking();
  }
}
```

My page content is then:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Test</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>
  <button (click)="startTracking()">
    Start Tracking
  </button>
  <button (click)="stopTracking()">
    Stop Tracking
  </button>

  <ion-item>Latitude / Longitude</ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      {{locationProvider.latitude}},{{locationProvider.longitude}}
    </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

When I compile my app for iOS and run in Xcode it looks as I expect, when I click the "Start Tracking" button I see entries in the Xcode console that suggest the location is being obtained correctly i.e.

```
2016-08-06 12:37:17:370 Test[3264:62403] Better location found: Location: id=0 time=140310177131584 lat=51.8724580445 lon=-2.26443678245263 accu=5 aaccu=-1 speed=-1 head=-1 alt=0 type=current
2016-08-06 12:37:17:371 Test[3264:62403] LocationManager queue Location: id=0 time=140310177131584 lat=51.8724580445 lon=-2.26443678245263 accu=5 aaccu=-1 speed=-1 head=-1 alt=0 type=current
2016-08-06 12:37:18:370 Test[3264:62403] LocationManager didUpdateLocations (operationMode: 1)
2016-08-06 12:37:18:370 Test[3264:62403] Location age 0.001122
2016-08-06 12:37:18:370 Test[3264:62403] Better location found: Location: id=0 time=140310177372752 lat=51.8726980292 lon=-2.26504136905789 accu=5 aaccu=-1 speed=-1 head=-1 alt=0 type=current
2016-08-06 12:37:18:370 Test[3264:62403] LocationManager queue Location: id=0 time=140310177372752 lat=51.8726980292 lon=-2.26504136905789 accu=5 aaccu=-1 speed=-1 head=-1 alt=0 type=current
```

But the co-ordinates displayed on the page never seem to refresh and update the true location.

Im probably missing the obvious, but can't see it, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have the same issue as well, as the author i can view the console log in Xcode and get locations as the author but the success callback is never fired.

Comment: have you tried to `console.log(this.latitude, this.longitude)`  inside the `zone.run()` code?

Comment: @Akis The callback this.locationUpdated is not fired at all.

Comment: same for me on android

Answer (score 0):

You may have solved this problem by now, but the problem is with this line:

```
BackgroundGeolocation.configure(config)
 .then(this.locationUpdated) <-----
 .catch((error) => {
      console.log('BackgroundGeolocation error');
  });
}
```

So your callback will get fired, but it will lose the context of *this*.

You will need to send the correct context of this, by using *.bind()*

```
BackgroundGeolocation.configure(config)
 .then(this.locationUpdated.bind(this)) <-----
 .catch((error) => {
      console.log('BackgroundGeolocation error');
  });
}
```